# Unable to open UDP socket

Tags: c++, boost, udp

I'm trying to create a UDP socket with boost to send and receive data. Here's the relevant code:

```
// Create IO service
mIoService = std::make_unique<boost::asio::io_service>();

// Create local endpoint on random port
mLocalEndpoint = std::make_unique<udp::endpoint>(udp::v4(), 0);

// Create socket
mSocket = std::make_unique<udp::socket>(*mIoService, *mLocalEndpoint);
mSocket->open(mLocalEndpoint->protocol());
```

This gives me the following exception:

> open: Already open

I have fiddled around with this code for quite some time now, but the result stays the same. What am I missing here?

Comment: As far as I’ve understood you don’t need to use `open`, you just start receiving on the socket and that’s it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you try to create a UDP end point on port `0`. I'd assume that it may be already used, so you can try to change a port:

```
mLocalEndpoint = std::make_unique<udp::endpoint>(udp::v4(), 40000);
```